# What are the performance differences between all the ways to declare a constant in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm, kotlinc

Since Kotlin doesn't allow you to directly declare constants inside a `class` like `static` members in Java, we have a couple of options on how to do it in Kotlin. My question is, what are the performance costs of each option, and which one is cheaper? I don't want to know which one is more readable or considered best-practice, I only want it from a performance perspective.

### Option 1: Use a companion object

So a code that looks like this:

```
class Thing {
    companion object {
        const val TAG = "Thing"
    }

   ...
}
```

In Java looks like this:

```
public final class Thing {
   public static final String TAG = "Thing";
   public static final Thing.Companion Companion = new Thing.Companion((DefaultConstructorMarker)null);

   public static final class Companion {
      private Companion() {
      }

      public Companion(DefaultConstructorMarker $constructor_marker) {
         this();
      }
   }

   ...
}
```

It creates this inner class `Companion` and instantiates it. How costly is this?

### Option 2: Declare it as a top-level variable

So this:

```
const val TAG = "Thing"
class Thing {
   ...
}
```

Becomes this:

```
public final class ThingKt {
   public static final String TAG = "Thing";
}

public final class Thing { ... }
```

It creates a new class with a `static` member. How different is this than using an object to store it?

### Option 3: Use an external object

Like so:

```
object ThingConstants {
    const val TAG = "Thing"
}

class Thing { ... }
```

Which in Java looks like this:

```
public final class ThingConstants {
   public static final String TAG = "Thing";
   public static final ThingConstants INSTANCE;

   ...  // Private constructor
}

public final class Thing { ... }
```

So similar to declaring as top-level, except the created class has an `INSTANCE` field that is initialized in a private constructor. How costlier is this compared to using a top-level variable?

### Option 4: Drop the const modifier

So you just use the good old `val`:

```
class Thing {
    val TAG = "Thing"
    
    ...
}
```

This is a mystery to me. It doesn't create any additional classes, but doesn't reap the benefits of the `const` modifier either. This means each instance of the class is going to have its own instance of `TAG`, as well as generating getters and setters for it too, right? But I also [read](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/best-practice-where-to-put-my-class-constants/15395/8) that the JVM optimizes it as a constant. So there is more to this option than I initially thought.

Comment: In practice, I'd be hugely surprised if _any_ of the above had a measurable impact on performance. (Depending upon the alignment and packing of objects on your platform, even option 4 might not need any extra memory, regardless of any optimisations.) Any real program will almost certainly have far greater opportunities for optimisation — in general, 20% of the code takes 80% of the time (the [80/20 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle#In_computing)), though it can take some effort to find that 20%!

Answer (score 2):

Options 1-3 are the same for performance because they are all `const` so they are inlined wherever used at compile time.

Option 4 doesn’t create duplicate instances of the String for each instance of the class. Instead each instance of the class will have a member field that points at the same shared instance. As far as performance, it is technically having to call a getter method each time it is retrieved but I would expect modern VMs to optimize that overhead away at runtime.

Options 1-3 do create extra Java class definitions so there is a bit more up front memory overhead for them. But if you already have other members in those objects or top levels of file, you already have those classes anyway. Option 4 has an extra field in the class so it could weigh more if there are a lot of instances of the class.